# How to import a Data set from ADO Query in Delphi (or check if it exist in the database table)

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access-2010, ado, delphi-10.3-rio

**USING DELPHI 10.3 + MS ACCESS 2010**

So I am basically trying to check if a dataset (like a **username** or **password** in a login/sign up form) exist in the database table..

I am using Microsoft Access as of my Database, and with the following configured components:

- ADOConnection
- ADOQuery
- DataSource
- ADOTable

my question is , how can I call for the results/import the results and check if it exist or not from the database from the ADOQuery or something..

my understanding is that I have to use  the ADOQuery.SQL strings to do so?, but I am not quiet sure how to actually make it work. (im obviously new to this)

if you have an answer that would be appreciated A lot!, if you need more questions I will try to answer you, with screenshots if necessary

**> PS: you can make a sample, simple one to help me out understand the details**

Comment: If you use a TAdoQuery to access the table, you can use its `Locate` method to determine whether it already contains a given username and its `Insert` method to add a new user's details.  Then call its `ApplyUpdates` method to update the database.  Btw, NEVER store a user's password in plain text a database, preferably store only a hash of it instead.

Comment: hey @MartynA can you also add some example on that one? i might try and see if it fits my needs, that would be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't store your password in plain text. Store a hashed version of it . When it is time to check the password, hash the input and compare the hashes in your SELECT statement.

Comment: Yuo're asking for a *how do I use a database in Delphi* tutorial. You can find such a tutorial in various places via a simple internet search.

Comment: @KenWhite i appreciate your comment about that title, i did try to do some researches on google/youtube on how i can do something like this but i ddint find what i needed exactly, this is why whenever i stuck on stuff like this i come to stackoverflow, sorry if my English is bad too or if my explanation isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your login validation, use something like this (Out of my memory, not tested):

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT UserCode FROM Credentials ' +
                      'WHERE (UserCode = :UserCode) ' +
                        'AND (Password = :Password)';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('UserCode').Value := FUserCode;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Password').Value := FPassword;
ADOQuery1.Open;
if ADOQuery1.Eof then
    ShowMessage('Invalid credentials')
else
    ShowMessage('OK')
```

BTW: Not a good idea to store the password in the database. Use a hash code instead.

BTW2: I returned UserCode, but probably you would return some more useful information like permission, last login or other. I don't know what you have at hand.

To create the username/password in the database, you could do something like this:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Credentials (UserCode, Password) ' +
                      'VALUES (:UserCode, :Password)';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('UserCode').Value := FUserCode;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Password').Value := FPassword;
ADOQuery1.ExecSql;
```

With this code, you see how to write data to the database. As stated in your comment, the "import" is to write data from Delphi to database. That is write data to the database. The code above is what you need. There is no difference in writing a username or any other data.

I strongly advice you to read a good book (or online) about SQL!
And also a book about Delphi.

Comment: im taking notes from your answer, the Hash code is also in my "Todo list"


also:
to import data, the direction I am willing to use is: from the Delphi program, if I click on the button for example "Sign Up" to create a new account, it would first verify if the **Username(or UserCode)** already exist in the database table, if not a new account will be created, so I think from what you said is the `SELECT` Statement will help with that one right?

Comment: The code in my answer is to check if username/password are already created in the database.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to write usercode/password to database. Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it answer your question. Feel free to ask more questions as question not as comment to an existing question.

Comment: thank you so much @fpiette and everyone else too, it worked out for me, i appreciate you!